# Link color not working

Tags: css

my site is [**this**](http://www.trackschoolbus.com/blog/rfid-helps-improve-fleet-efficiency-productivity/) . the end of the content has a paragrapgh with three external links .the color for each anchor text is set to #555 now. i need to make it #4293f1 .
 so i added the below css to my style.css

html

```
<a class="zem_slink" title="Supply chain management" href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supply_chain_management" target="_blank" rel="wikipedia">supply chain management</a>
```

css

```
.blog-article dl .blog-content .zem_slink{color:#4293f1!important;}
```

also i tried

```
a.zem_slink{color:#4293f1!important;}
```

both didnt work.

please help

Comment: Can you apply the a.zem_slink rule, and upload it?

Comment: Are you sure that adding the below line to your CSS doesn't work? I can't see this value in your stylesheet?

    .zem_slink {color:#4293f1;}

Comment: I've checked the URL that you provided, I can't see any changes has been made. Can you check back again? Did your css file linked properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working:

```
.blog-article dl .blog-content a.zem_slink {
    color: #4293f1;
}
```

Update your **CSS** properly on server. Then clear your cache [Press Ctrl+F5] to see the changes.

Comment: i didn't see you update it on server. Did you made changes to your **eldo.css** file?

Comment: also, add this **rule** at the bottom of your **css** file.

Answer (score 0):

CSS for links are a bit differents :

```
/* unvisited link */
a.zem_slink:link {
    color: #4293f1;
}

/* visited link */
a.zem_slink:visited {
    color: #4293f1;
}

/* mouse over link */
a.zem_slink:hover {
    color: #4293f1;
}

/* selected link */
a.zem_slink:active {
    color: #4293f1;
}
```

Comment: This will change ALL links to the colors stated, which may not be what the author wants, as he/she specifically included classes with the links.

Comment: @Lee Yes the point was just to demonstrate how to use the `:visited` and `:link`. Here you go for the specific

Comment: I modified your CSS it totally works. be sure not to add spaces. `a.zem_slink:link { color: #4293F1; }`

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS Stylesheet try adding this:

```
.zem_slink a:hover{
    color: #4293f1; 
}

.zem_slink a:active{
    color: #4293f1;
}

.zem_slink a:visited{
    color: #4293f1;
}
```